# Проблема с DOM. НЕ могу получить элемент

Tags: javascript, dom

Народ, подскажите, где я косячу. Ни чего не происходит

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Пользователи:</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Джон</li>
      <li>Пит</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

А это скрипт

```
alert(document.body.div);
```

Comment: Вы в алерте хотите вывести надпись "Пользователи:" ?

Answer (score 2):

Как вы можете видеть, [у элемента `body` нет свойства `div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body). Не все потомки элемента можно получить через свойства, это скорее исключение. Но можно работать с [методом `.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelector):

```js
alert(document.body.querySelector('div').innerText);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Пользователи:</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Джон</li>
      <li>Пит</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```